# SElinux denies to access file in /proc

Tags: selinux, proc

My audit plugin process needs to be able to iterate through `/proc` and read `/proc/pid/stat` files, but SElinux refuses this.

Process context of my plugin:

```
ps auxZ | grep -i myplugin
system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0   root        8143  0.3  0.3  96188  6284 ?        D<l       11:02   0:00 myplugin
```

Example of log of denying: `type=AVC msg=audit(1705309402.866:1150): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=8143 comm="myplugin" path="/proc/42" dev="proc" ino=95999 scontext=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0`

I solved this problem by creating a selinux policy using `audit2allow`, it read the audit log and created the necessary `allow` statements. But the `.te` file turned out to be too large and unreadable, more than 100 lines. Moreover, if I understand correctly, this is an unreliable solution, because, for example, the next time you run the plugin and iterate through `/proc`, there may already be some new process and, accordingly, a new file in `/proc` with a new security context that was not in that time when I did `audit2allow` and there is no `allow` statement for this file in my policy. As a result, SElinux will refuse access to this new file.

Is there some simpler and more reliable way to solve this problem? Essentially, I need a policy that states that such and such a process can read all files in `/proc` without listing every possible file.